# Missing "key" prop for element in iteratoreslintreact/jsx-key

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js

The following part is returning `Missing "key" prop for element in iteratoreslintreact/jsx-key`

```
{[...Array(10)].map((_) => (
  <Skeleton variant="rectangular" sx={{ my: 4, mx: 1 }} />
))}
```

I tried to fix it as following:

```
{[...Array(10)].map((x) => (
  <Skeleton variant="rectangular" sx={{ my: 4, mx: 1 }} key="x.id" />
))}
```

but I'm not quite sure if it's correct.

### Full code

```cs
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { DataGrid, GridColDef } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { Card, Paper } from '@mui/material';
import Skeleton from '@mui/material/Skeleton';
import { amber, orange } from '@mui/material/colors';

import FormOne from './../src/FormOne';

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID' },
  { field: 'title', headerName: 'Title', width: 300 },
  { field: 'body', headerName: 'Body', width: 600 },
];

const LoadingSkeleton = () => (
  <Box
    sx={{
      height: 'max-content',
    }}
  >
    {[...Array(10)].map((_) => (
      <Skeleton variant="rectangular" sx={{ my: 4, mx: 1 }} />
    ))}
  </Box>
);

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  // fetch data from fake API
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(
      () =>
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            setPosts(data);
            setLoading(false);
          }),
      3000
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container
      maxWidth={false}
      sx={{
        height: '100vh',
        overflow: 'auto',
        paddingRight: '0px !important',
        paddingLeft: '0px !important',
        background: `linear-gradient(to right, ${amber[300]}, ${orange[500]})`,
      }}
    >
      <Card
        sx={{ marginBottom: 10, padding: 10, marginLeft: 25, marginRight: 25 }}
      >
        <FormOne />
      </Card>

      <Card sx={{ marginLeft: 25, marginRight: 25 }}>
        <Paper sx={{ padding: 5, height: '800px' }}>
          <DataGrid
            rows={posts}
            columns={columns}
            pageSize={10}
            autoHeight
            rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
            disableSelectionOnClick
            disableColumnMenu
            disableColumnSelector
            components={{
              LoadingOverlay: LoadingSkeleton,
            }}
            loading={loading}
          />
        </Paper>
      </Card>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a unique id for each item. In your code `key="x.id"`, `"x.id"` is just a string, which means it's the same for all items, that's incorrect

If you have unique ids for each item, use them. Otherwise, you may use indexes as keys:

```
{[...Array(10)].map((x, index) => (
  <Skeleton variant="rectangular" sx={{ my: 4, mx: 1 }} key={index} />
))}
```

Read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)